# sum of dynamic columns based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get sum of dynamic columns based on certain condition.

```
cols = ['ID','A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
```

dataframe df has all the columns listed above.

If ID = 2, I need sum of first two columns A, B
IF ID = 3, I need sum of first three columns A,B,C

```
df.loc['SUM'] = df.loc[df['ID'] > 0,cols[0:df['ID']]].sum(axis=1)
```

above line of code is giving an error that :

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

**Note :** ID can be any number but it would be always less than or equal to total number of columns

There are no nan and missing values in dataframe.

Comment: Can ID only be 2 or 3? Also, what about NaNs and junk data in ID column?

Comment: Please add a data sample with your expected output.

Comment: ID can be any number but it would be always less than or equal to total number of columns .

Comment: Ah, that is probably crucial information you should include in the question -- it will influence the usefulness of the answers you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vectorise this thanks to the power of NumPy:

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df.wherenp.arange(df.shape[1]) < df.index.values[:,None]).sum(axis=1)
```

---

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__
# '0.24.2'

np.random.seed(0) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 8))) 
df.insert(0, 'ID', np.random.randint(1, 8, 5))  
df                                           

   ID  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0   4  6  1  4  4  8  4  6  3
1   7  5  8  7  9  9  2  7  8
2   4  8  9  2  6  9  5  4  1
3   3  4  6  1  3  4  9  2  4
4   5  4  4  8  1  2  1  5  8
```

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df.assign(
    SUM=df.where(np.arange(df.shape[1]) < df.index.values[:,None]).sum(axis=1))

    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   SUM
ID                              
4   6  1  4  4  8  4  6  3  15.0
7   5  8  7  9  9  2  7  8  47.0
4   8  9  2  6  9  5  4  1  25.0
3   4  6  1  3  4  9  2  4  11.0
5   4  4  8  1  2  1  5  8  19.0
```

The `where` function will hide values that we don't want to sum over:

```
df.where(np.arange(df.shape[1]) < df.index[:,None])   

    0  1  2    3    4    5    6   7
ID                                 
4   6  1  4  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
7   5  8  7  9.0  9.0  2.0  7.0 NaN
4   8  9  2  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3   4  6  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
5   4  4  8  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Thanks to @Quang Hoang for pointing out a potential bug in the solution.

Comment: `np.arange(df.shape[1]) < df.index[:,None]` gives me an error. May be `np.arange(df.shape[1]) < df.index.values[:,None]`

Comment: Mine is python 3.7, pandas 0.24.2: `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Comment: @QuangHoang I have python3.6, numpy 1.15, and pandas 0.24.2. You say `df.index.values[:,None]` works, yes? I can add a note but I can't reproduce your error so not sure what much else I can do :p

Comment: I see where your problem might be. Change the number of columns to `8` as in the question.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, I see it too! Funny behaviour and thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

with df :

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   
ID                              
4   6  1  4  4  8  4  6  3  
7   5  8  7  9  9  2  7  8  
4   8  9  2  6  9  5  4  1 
3   4  6  1  3  4  9  2  4  
5   4  4  8  1  2  1  5  8
```

sums are computed by `df.cumsum(axis=1).values[range(len(df)),df.index-1]`

it's 5x faster than   `df.where(np.arange(df.shape[1]) <df.index.values[:,None]).sum(axis=1)`.